# SingularValueDecomposition causes kernel crash in 11.3

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra, crash

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 11.3 or later**

---

```
test = Table[RandomReal[{-2, 2}], {3600}, {11}];

Dimensions[test]
```

> {3600, 11}

Calling `SingularValueDecomposition` on `test` crashes the kernel:

```
{u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[test];
```

Version 11.3 running on Windows 7 (64 bit).

Can anyone duplicate this behavior?

Comment: This has no bearing on your question, but your `Table` can just be `test = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {3600, 11}]`.

Comment: It spins for a while for me, which suggests it's just eating up too much memory (I didn't let it crash). Same thing happens with `Eigensystem` on big matrices.

Comment: Thanks for testing. `ByteCount` shows the matrix `test` is only 300KB in size. I don't believe memory use could be the issue. BTW 11.2 works fine.

Comment: 11.2 shows that `ByteCount[u]` (largest resulting matrix) is 100MB.

Comment: If there're a bunch of copies of intermediate matrices floating around that'll crunch things. Check ``MaxMemoryUsed[]``.

Comment: In 11.2 `MaxMemoryUsed[]` is 750MB (my PC has 32GB).

Comment: To help with diagnosis: does `SingularValueList[]` work on your computer with the same matrix?

Comment: Yes `SingularValueList[test]` completes without issues.

Comment: Works fine for me on version 13.3 on macos 10.13.3...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You coming from the future? Good to know they fixed it by then... :)

Comment: @gwr Sorry, I mean version 11.3... =D But let me assure you that they won't have been able to fix the front-end issues in version 13.3... ;)

Comment: Your three-line codes just work well on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Just a side question: are you sure you need the full SVD? You might consider computing the truncated SVD instead, which should take up significantly less memory and for many purposes it should suffice: `SingularValueDecomposition[test, Min[Dimensions[test]]]`. See also the "Possible Issues" section in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted support and here is their response:

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> I was able to reproduce the issue, and consequently, I filed a report
>   with our development team raising the issues and also included your
>   contact information with them so you can be notified once the issue is
>   resolved.

Answer (score 4):

So I thought I could replicate this on Mac (I can't) but I can instead show a different *front-end* bug.

Consider this:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

38222504

SingularValueDecomposition@
  RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {3600, 11}] // ByteCount

103998304

MaxMemoryUsed[]

141054992
```

This is fast.

But if I try to display the resultant matrix instead of just calling `ByteCount` it takes ~1 min and suddenly I've use ~2 GB of memory:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

1994237832
```

Comment: I observe the same with version 11.3 on macos. However, note that the first entry of the resulting list is a 3600 x 3600 matrix. It is not unusual that the front-end chokes when told to display matrices of this size...

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work fine under 11.3 on Linux x64 with 64GB ....

```
test = Table[RandomReal[{-2, 2}], {3600}, {11}];
{u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[test];
```

gets me

```
s = 
{{72.0325,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,70.9864,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,70.4064,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}, \[CenterEllipsis]3595\[CenterEllipsis] ,{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}}
```

with

```
Dimensions[#] & /@ {u, s, v}
```

as expected.

Comment: It seems that `[#]&` is redundant :).