# SingularValueDecomposition crashes kernel?

Tags: kernel, crash, stability

Consider the following simple example (Windows 10, MA 11.3)

```
mat = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 2000}, {i, 1, 2500}];
{u, ww, vt} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat];
```

After the `SingularValueDecomposition` finishes, Mathematica makes a "ding" sound and the kernel quits. My system has a lot of RAM and it does not look like it is close to running out. What may be the reason for the crash, and how to fix this?

EDIT:

As pointed out by rhermans, the random example does not always produce a crash, so I have uploaded an example matrix here:

https://gofile.io/?c=k06dAL

that produces such a crash on a fresh kernel.

EDIT2:

```
SeedRandom[1000]
mat = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 2000}, {i, 1, 2500}];
{u, ww, vt} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat];
```

also seems to consistently crash in this fashion.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem neither in Mathematica 11.3 nor 12 on Windows 7 64. Does it happens with a fresh kernel? Can you reproduce it with a particular `SeedRandom`?

Comment: @rhermans It happens on a fresh kernel with the following mat http://gofile.io/?c=k06dAL , now the file appears to have posted.

Comment: It would be easier if you gave a `SeedRandom` than asking people to download a file.

Comment: @rhermans on my end `SeedRandom[1000]` also seems to cause such a crash consistently.

Comment: Still can't reproduce it on my computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169586/singularvaluedecomposition-causes-kernel-crash-in-11-3